# How to properly sort the table in excel with fractions formatted as text?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

How to sort this in excel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWAQ.jpg)
Eartag table to Output shown in the picture

Please see attached picture for the output reference.

Comment: Explain little more. How 17/14 becoming 370?

Comment: @Harun24hr I guess he wants to SORT, so 17/14 is not becoming 370, just moved the sort order.

Comment: @Prema Hard to guess. If so, then second highest should be `90/4` but OP showing `5\4`. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Harun24hr I thought like you first, I had the solution, then I saw he want not sort the fraction but the numbers before and after the slash

Answer (score 0):

Here several steps to sort it.

1. Extrakt First and Second part of number
2. Copy and paste values
3. Advanced sorting second part, then first part
4. write formula to make a text string again.

Or see what Harun24hr will come up with :-)

```
=VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(A3;"/";;;;A3))
=VALUE(TEXTAFTER(A3;"/";;;;0))
=IF(D18>0;C18&"\"&D18;C18)
```

[image]

Comment: If this is what OP wants then could use `=SORTBY(A3:A12,--IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(A3:A12,"/"),0),1,--TEXTBEFORE(A3:A12,"/",,,1),1)` as single formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr I knew you would come up with something better. Thank you for sharing your skills and helping so many people! Great service!